# HTML select dropdown custom arrow css

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, html-select

I am trying to use a custom arrow for a dropdown menu as mentioned in the code. I am facing two issues here.

1.unable to place the arrow section adjacent to the dropdwon.

2.This custom arrow is not clickable.

How can I achieve these two ?

I tried to use `z-index;-1` for the `:after` section. But its not working as expected.

```css
  
.expenses_div {
 
 width:90% !important;
 margin:auto;
 margin-top:2%;

}

 
.expenses_div_left{
 height:40px;
 line-height:40px;
 background-color:black; 
 float:left;
 display: inline-block;
 text-align:left;
 padding-left:12px;
 color:white;
 width:48%;
 font-size: 14px !important;
 font-family : "Montserrat",sans-serif !important;
 
 } 
 
.expenses_div_right{
 
 height: 40px !important;
 line-height: 40px !important;
 width:48%;
 float:left;
 display: inline-block;
 cursor:pointer;
 background:transparent !important;
 
}



 
.expenses_div_right select {

 font-family : "Montserrat",sans-serif !important;
 background:transparent !important;
 appearance:none !important;
 -moz-appearance:none !important;
 -webkit-appearance:none !important;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box !important;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box !important;
 box-sizing: border-box !important;
 border: 1px solid black !important;
 width:100%!important;
 color:black !important;
 height:40px;
 text-align:left !important;
 font-size: 14px !important;
 outline: none; 
 background-color:none !important;
 position: relative !important;
 cursor:pointer;
 padding-left:12px;
  
}
 

.expenses_div_right:after { 
 content: '< >';
 font: 16px "Consolas", monospace;
 font-weight:bold;
 color: white;
 background-color:black;
  display:inline-block;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
 transform: rotate(90deg);
 position: relative;
 width:40px;
 height:40px;
 text-align:center;
 line-height:40px;
 overflow:hidden !important;
 cursor:pointer;

}
```

```html
<div class="expenses_div">
   <div class="expenses_div_left" >How to Proceed</div>
   <div class="expenses_div_right" >
    <select name="main_selection"  id="main_selection" >
     <option selected value="">Select an option</option>
     <option value="new_data">New Data</option>
     <option value="analize_data">Analyze Data</option>
     <option value="refresh_data">Refresh Data</option> 
    </select>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Position And Click !

**Changes commented :**

**Snippet :**

```css
.expenses_div {

width:90% !important;
margin:auto;
margin-top:2%;

}


.expenses_div_left{
height:40px;
line-height:40px;
background-color:black; 
float:left;
display: inline-block;
text-align:left;
padding-left:12px;
color:white;
width:48%;
font-size: 14px !important;
font-family : "Montserrat",sans-serif !important;

} 

.expenses_div_right{

height: 40px !important;
line-height: 40px !important;
width:48%;
float:left;
display: inline-block;
cursor:pointer;
background:transparent !important;
position:relative;/*Added (Because :after should be relative to this not whole page! )*/

}




.expenses_div_right select {

font-family : "Montserrat",sans-serif !important;
background:transparent !important;
appearance:none !important;
-moz-appearance:none !important;
-webkit-appearance:none !important;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box !important;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box !important;
box-sizing: border-box !important;
border: 1px solid black !important;
width:100%!important;
color:black !important;
height:40px;
text-align:left !important;
font-size: 14px !important;
outline: none; 
background-color:none !important;
position: relative !important;
cursor:pointer;
padding-left:12px;

}


.expenses_div_right:after { 
content: '< >';
font: 16px "Consolas", monospace;
font-weight:bold;
color: white;
background-color:black;
display:inline-block;
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
transform: rotate(90deg);
position: absolute;/*Changed to absolute*/
top:0;/*Added*/
right:0;/*Added*/
width:40px;
height:40px;
text-align:center;
line-height:40px;
overflow:hidden !important;
cursor:pointer;
z-index :-1 ;/*Added ( For Your 2nd Question )*/
}
```

```html
<div class="expenses_div">
   <div class="expenses_div_left" >How to Proceed</div>
   <div class="expenses_div_right" >
    <select name="main_selection"  id="main_selection" >
     <option selected value="">Select an option</option>
     <option value="new_data">New Data</option>
     <option value="analize_data">Analyze Data</option>
     <option value="refresh_data">Refresh Data</option> 
    </select>
   </div>
  </div>
```

**I hole this helps you !**

Comment: Thanks. But when I add this code to my site, arrow is not showing up. arrow is positioned properly. verified that with removing the z-index. I believe there is something strange with background:transparent !important; property. its not working as expected

Comment: Happy to help ;) please send your website url or run it on js-fiddle to see whats wrong

Comment: add : z-index:2; to <select> and change z-index :after to z-index:1;that will work:)